# Is there a C++11 strncmp alternative that performs as well?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to look for a prefix in a string.  I have been using this:

```
if (s.substr (0, 7) == "prefix_")
  ...
```

While this works, it is relatively slower than `strncmp`, as shown by this test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  std::string s = "prefix_this is a passing test that will always match";

  auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    if (s.substr (0, 7) == "prefix_")
      ;

  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    if (! s.compare (0, 7, "prefix_", 0, 7))
      ;

  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    if (! strncmp (s.c_str (), "prefix_", 7))
      ;

  auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();

  std::cout << "[1] s.substr (0, 7) == \"prefix_\"          "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count()
            << " μs\n"
            << "[2] ! strncmp (s.c_str (), \"prefix_\", 7)  "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
            << " μs\n"
            << "[3] ! s.compare (0, 7, \"prefix_\", 0, 7)   "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t3 - t2).count()
            << " μs\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I am seeing this performance, which surprised me:

```
[1] s.substr (0, 7) == "prefix_"          33022 μs
[2] ! strncmp (s.c_str (), "prefix_", 7)  32547 μs
[3] ! s.compare (0, 7, "prefix_", 0, 7)   12953 μs
```

I would prefer to use C++11, without dropping back to libc, but the results are not good.

Comment: I'm sure that there are absolutely no awkward compiler opts given that the result of those comparisons are completely unsued.

Comment: What is wrong with option #3, exactly? It seems to be what you are looking for?? As for the "surprise", #1 constructs a temporary string and #2 has to do an extra check for `\0` on each character comparison.

Comment: Can you provide benchmarks for `strcmp`, the target you are supposed to be hitting, also?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The printing code is wrong. The actual run order is `substr`, `compare`, then`strncmp`.

Comment: I do not trust this benchmark, gcc -O2 optimizes away only the third loop (which then takes, surprise, 0 ns). The results are meaningless.

Comment: @T.C.: lmao!​​​ Alright, I'm downvoting. Too many problems with this question. I'm surprised I'm the first.

Comment: @BaummitAugen And clang -O3 appears to optimize away all three loops (at least with libc++) :)

Comment: @T.C. And it does not with libstdc++. :) Whatever, just shows how horribly broken this "benchmark" is. Hail to the upvote zombies who are to lazy to think before voting.

Comment: therefore the irrelevant results.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham That makes matters even more nonsensical. Performance of unoptimized C++ code is meaningless, this is by design of the language.

Comment: Also, `s.compare (0, 7, "prefix_", 0, 7)` hits the overload of `compare` taking a `basic_string`. You want the overload taking a `const char *`, `s.compare (0, 7, "prefix_", 7)`.

Comment: @T.C.: Yay, that means my answer is not quite redundant ;)

Answer (score 13):

**Yes.**

You may avoid the string construction with the following, which is the *actual* analogue to `strncmp`:

```
if (s.compare(0, 7, "prefix_") == 0) {}
```

In reality, of course, I'd recommend not hardcoding that *n* value.

As always, simply spending five minutes perusing a standard library reference [goes a long way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)…

Comment: In fact I just noticed you already used this in your question. So now I'm really confused as to what you're asking. "Hello here's the fastest way in C++ to compare a string prefix. How can I compare a string prefix in C++?" wtf

Comment: oooh did not know about `s.compare` :) i guess that it would be trivial to make something that wraps over this and takes `str_const`, or uses the trick in the str_const constructor where you take a reference to `const char []` and deduce the size of the string literal as a template parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you can use boost (obligatory warning), you can write this also as

```
if(boost::string_ref(s).substr(0, 7) == "prefix_")
   ...
```

In fact, this is one of its introductory examples. Altenatively

```
 if(boost::string_ref(s).starts_with("prefix_"))
   ...
```

The latter is different, in that there is no undefined behavior if your string actually has less than 7 characters :)

Comment: I reinvented precisely this for the same use case not long ago :D